# Empty request data from ajax in laravel 5.4

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to change a value based on the selected year and week with ajax.

This is my ajax function:

```
function changeBekeken() {
        var year = $("#jaar-nr").val();
        var week = $("#week-nr").val();
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: "/planning/viewed",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                year_nr: year,
                week_nr: week
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#week-nr").change(function(){
            changeBekeken();
        });
        $("#jaar-nr").change(function(){
            changeBekeken();
        });
    });
```

This is the route:

```
Route::post('/planning/viewed', 'PlanningController@viewed');
```

The data is send to a controller function:

```
public function viewed(Request $request) {
    $check = DB::table('planning_files')
        ->where([
            ['user_id', Auth::user()->id],
            ['created_year', $request->input('year_nr')],
            ['week', $request->input('week_nr')],
        ])
        ->select('seen')
        ->first();
    if($check) {
        return json_encode($check, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    } else {
        return json_encode(false);
    }
}
```

However even when I use $request->all(); request is always empty. My function will always return false. Pretty much this exact same function works on another page, but I can't seem to get this one working.

I have tried adding some extra information to the ajax function, like content type and data type, but none seem to work.

Any tips?

**Edit 1**

These are the namespaces and classes I use in my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Storage;
```

**Edit 2**

When I copy the function to another page it works properly. It has something to do with the content on the page I use the ajax function on. Probably some conflict with the token. I will try to resolve this and post the answer for others if they might have the same problem in the future.

Comment: Is there any content at all in the request if you do `dd($request)`?

Comment: Can you post full controller page or show what namespaces are at the top?

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Murray Yes, dd($request) gives me an object with data, although my input isn't found in that list.

Comment: @Rahi edited my post, check edit 1. There is a function in the same controller that does work with ajax and returns the proper data. This function does not work properly however.

Comment: To me, it sounds like a problem with the javascript, not laravel.... You could use the beforeSend method (see: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to check if you indeed have fields? And are your field populated? There is a middleware in 5.4 that transforms empty fields in `null`...

Comment: Are you using Chrome? If yes, you can check what is sent in ajax call under network tab and it might tell if issue is on jQuery side or laravel.

Comment: @rahi the formdata actually exists on the network tab (year: 2017 and week: 14 for example). Although the result will still be false, or null after removing the if statement from the controller.

Comment: @jean-PhilippeMurray the fields exist. Even when I use hardcoded data in the ajax function it will still return false.

Comment: Are you using SanitizeMiddleware? I don't see that added in your Routes but if it there disable it and retry.